# How to pass a specific collection to an Info Collection node?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, collections

In the official documentation on [`Node Parts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/parts.html) it mentions about white colored socket inputs of the [`Collection Input Node`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/collection_info.html) (its official documentation also doesn't mention much, only says "Collection to get the properties from").

> Collection (white)
>  Used to pass a collection data-block.

But I can't find any collection data-block based Nodes which can connect to this. How to pass a specific collection to an *Info Collection* node in Blender 3.0.1?

@Chris: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. But I need it to be inside the node editor so I can do some conditional stuff as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can connect it to the group input node ;)

[image]

Comment: that's a good point, i should mention that i want it to be in the node editor so i can do some conditional stuff :) i'll update my post. EDIT: oh i can just create a group i guess

Comment: or i can just duplicate the collection info and assign different collections to each node XD

Comment: that happens to me so often, i get an answer and it helps me anyway - although it might not be the "exact" answer i was looking for :D

Comment: yeah exactly that's so true! :D